# AngularJS: How to filter an object on every loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, controller, restangular

I'm building app using AngularJs and Restangular for REST services.

Now I have a form where I must allow user to add o a multiple objects from object list, using select. 
But every time the user chooses one object from select I need to filter out that object from the list for the next select.

I've tried to create a copy of an object array and remove items I've added in previous selects but I can't access $scope.purpose.purpose inside my controller, only in template.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="i in hardware.purposes track by $index">
   <form-label>Namjena: {{i}}</form-label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control" placeholder=""
      ng-model="hardware.purposes[$index]" ng-required="true" >
          <option ng-repeat="item in purpose.purpose" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-1">
     <button type="button" href="" ng-model="button" ng-click="addNewPurpose()" ng-disabled="addMoreDisabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('AddHardwareCtrl',
function HardwareListCtrl($scope, PurposeService, $location, $route, $routeParams) {

    $scope.purpose = PurposeService.one().get().$object;

    $scope.hardware = {
        name: "",
        description: "",
        laboratory: "",
        organization: "",
        owner: "",
        purposes: [""],
        contact_person: "",
        purchase_value: "",
        acquisition_date: Date.now()
    };

    $scope.addNewPurpose = function() {
        $scope.hardware.purposes.push("");

        if($scope.hardware.purposes.length == $scope.purpose.purpose.length){
            $scope.addMoreDisabled = true;
        }
        else{
            $scope.addMoreDisabled = false;
        }
    };

});
```

Can somebody please help me? I'm trying to solve this problem for the last 5 days it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I would just have two lists, and move the item from list 1 to list 2. No filtering required. When you add it to list 2, remove it from list 1. If you need the original list again, you can get it from the original promise/service

Comment: I tought about that but I cant access the $scope.purpose.purpose object array inside of controller, I can only access it in my HTML template.